# Connect react-redux with NodeJS (MySQL) - socket.io

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux

I'm new to `react-redux` and have a question that I've searched for but can't find a good answer. How can I connect my `react-redux` app to a backend and exactly what API should I be using for better results?

My back end is currently `NodeJS-MySQL` and I also use `Socket.io` on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect redux to an api via fetch calls. Usually this is done by creating actions and reducers. The fetch calls are usually made in an action using the thunk middleware. Here is a full example of how you would consume some data from reddit and populate your redux store https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.md

Concerning nodjs-mysql if you are familiar with this framework you would write your connection to the database and some node js code (endpoints) to receive the fetch api calls from react-redux. So essentially they are two different things. Your nodejs-mysql and nodejs code would act like a backend to react-redux.